# Wire size: is a 16 AWG wire the same 3x 23 AWG wires?

Tags: power-supply, power, cables, wire

I'm building an LED installation and I was wondering if I could use the cat6 cables I already have.  I've calculated the needed wire area to be 16 AWG (D 1.4mm, 1.65mm<sup>2</sup>) (for 5 meters).

Would this be the same as 3 twisted pairs of cat6 wires 23 AWG (D 0.57mm, 0.25mm<sup>2</sup>)?

The idea is to use two wires for data and the remaining 6 for either 3 positive and 3 negatives.

Comment: not even close. cross area on a 1.5mm wire is 1.76mm (pi*r^2), on a 0.57mm wire it's only 0.21mm, so you would need 8 or 9 smaller wires to form the equivalent cross-sectional area, not 3. This is why a wide short glass holds much more liquid than a tall narrow glass. That said, raise the voltage at one end and buck the other end so that your current is reduced, along with your copper requirements.

Comment: Hi @dandavis Thanks! I just came across this blogpost. Would you say this is not possible? https://blinkylights.blog/2022/05/23/single-cat-6-power-and-data-for-ws2815-led-strips/

Comment: maybe. it's hard for me to evaluate because it depends on too many unknown factors. I am sure that sending 24v or 36v across the CAT6 would slash your current requirements, and that quality 5/12v output DC-DC buck converter modules (i like XL-semi based ones) are under a few bucks each. That's how i power my intercom over phone lines; 2 signals, 2 power at 24v, stepped down to 9v at each panel to feed the audio chip amp.

Comment: PoE uses ~48V so you'd be able to go to at least that voltage without worrying about the wire insulation.  Depending on your configuration, you might be able to use a cheap PoE injector/splitter pair to take care of the wiring part for you.